# Presenting a long linear regression equation

Tags: equations

I am using the following code to have a long linear regression model in my **two-column** latex file. I have used `figure *` to avoid the overlapping of the equation with the second column. However, it doesn't look good to me. Could you please suggest me any better way for this.

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sf}
ua = (49.3) + (-13 * m\_a) + (-0.4 * k\_a) + (-1 * l\_b) + (8 * t\_b) + (-9 * s\_a)
\end{equation}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Your code snippet won't compile (after suitable completion) since you are enclosing the equation inside a `\mbox`. Can you please add turn your code snippet into a minimal compilable example? (Please add the document class used and any relevant package).

Comment: @Gonzalo: Could you please check now?

Comment: But you haven't provided the document class used.

Comment: @Gonzalo: ACM sig-alternate class.

Comment: Then put it in your example so that people can copy and paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what the problem is, but does this help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\op}{\,*\,}% Use \: instead of \, if you want larger space

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\begin{align} 
ua = (49.3) + (-13 * m\_a) + (-0.4 * k\_a) \notag\\
    \phantom{=}+ (-1 * l\_b) + (8 * t\_b) + (-9 * s\_a) \label{eq:sf}
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
ua = (49.3) + (-13 \op m\_a) + (-0.4 \op k\_a) \notag\\
    \phantom{=}+ (-1 \op l\_b) + (8 \op t\_b) + (-9 \op s\_a) \label{eq:sf}
\end{align}

\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

If you are looking to automatically break the equation that is a bit more complicated, and perhaps the [breqn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package may be useful to look into.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also help me to provide some space between the * operator and variables.

Comment: See updated solution. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    ua =&  (49.3) \\
        &+ (-13 * m\_a) \\
        &+ (-0.4 * k\_a) \\
        &+ (-1 * l\_b) \\
        &+ (8 * t\_b) \\
        &+ (-9 * s\_a)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

You have to `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble.

The [Short Math Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf)
introduces in page 2 other useful environments for formatting equations.